# How to render a component onClick with React?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx, google-maps-react

I'm trying to render a map of a specific location that's being passed from a parent component. I'm using google-maps-react and i'm unsure of two things:

How to call to functions with `onClick` inside my render. And how to write the function in my class that renders the component I want. This is wha tI have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import yelp from 'yelp-fusion';
import xhr from 'xhr';
import GoogleMapContainer from './Map';

class BusinessCard extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()

    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
  }

  renderMap(){
    <GoogleMapContainer barLat={bar.coordinates.latitude} barLong={bar.coordinates.longitude} />
  }

  render() {
    const newCard = this.props.newCard
    const bar = this.props.selectedBar
    // console.log("this are the coordinates", bar["coordinates"])
    if(bar.coordinates){
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{bar.coordinates.longitude}</p>
          <p>{bar.name}</p>
          <img src={bar.image_url} />
          <button> X </button>
          <button onClick={newCard}> Yes </button>

        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default BusinessCard;
```

At the moment, there's a problem with that compiling since `bar` is undefined when rendering. Any suggestions/advice?

Comment: Are you trying to optionally render the map if this.props.selectedBar is defined?

Comment: First of all,  your `renderMap()` should return the Jsx

Comment: And you are not using that anywhere

Comment: And what is `newCard`, is it a function? `onClick` is an event handler and expects a function that executes when that event is triggered - in your case, user presses on the button

Comment: Yeah, sorry still new to this, I was planning on calling the function `onClick` right next to `{newBar}` but I don't think I can call two functions with `onClick`. I just changed the renderMap function so it returns a div with JSX rendering the component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, in a React component, the [`render()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render) method is your bridge between the virtual DOM (kept in memory by React) and the concrete DOM that is shown to the user. I'd read more about a React [component's lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) - understanding this is understanding react.

Furthermore, in order to show your `GoogleMapContainer` on the page, you need to call your method `renderMap()` in the React `render()` method, store the result in a variable and return it.

For calling multiple functions in `onClick` that is totally possible, pass a function to the handler and call how many functions you want there.

Check this example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import yelp from 'yelp-fusion';
import xhr from 'xhr';
import GoogleMapContainer from './Map';

class BusinessCard extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    // LOOK MORE WHAT 'this' means!! <- the key of javascript = execution context
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  renderMap(){
    // careful!!! bar is undefined. Look more what 'this' means in javascript
    const bar = this.props.selectedBar;
    return (
      <GoogleMapContainer barLat={bar.coordinates.latitude} barLong={bar.coordinates.longitude} />
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    const newCard = this.props.newCard;

    // call the newCard function prop (if only is a function!!!)
    newCard();

    // another method call
    this.anotherMethod();
  }

  anotherMethod() {
    console.log('heyo!');
  }

  render() {
    const newCard = this.props.newCard
    const bar = this.props.selectedBar
    // console.log("this are the coordinates", bar["coordinates"])
    if(bar.coordinates){
      const renderMap = this.renderMap();
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{bar.coordinates.longitude}</p>
          <p>{bar.name}</p>
          <img src={bar.image_url} />
          <button> X </button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Yes </button>
          { renderMap }
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```